# Bootstrap date picker sends null value to cotroller from view when current date is set in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

My view looks like this

```
<div class="col-md-12 box-header">
    <?php echo form_open('admin/Inward/showreport', 'class="form-inline" style=""');?>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           <input id="date_1" value="<?php $from= $this->input->post('from');if($from){echo $from;}else{echo date('Y-m-d');}?>" name="from" class="form-control pull-left" type="date" placeholder=" From" />
                                    <p class="pull-left" style="font-size:10px;">From Date</p>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input id="date_2" value="<?php $to= $this->input->post('to');if($to){echo $to;}else{echo date('Y-m-d');}?>" name="to" class="form-control" type="date" placeholder=" To" />
                                    <p class="pull-left" style="font-size:10px;">To Date</p>
                                </div>
```

And controller  like this:

```
$to = $this->input->post('to');
      $from = $this->input->post('from');
      $dealer = $this->input->post('dealer');
      $product_type =implode('',$this->input->post('product_type'));

      $data['report'] = $this->Inward_model->allrecords($from,$to,$dealer,$product_type);

      $this->load->view('admin/reportlist', $data);
```

I am supposed to display records according to current date on page load, but instead it shows no records. When I var_dumped $from and $to it gave me null value. that is the current date in not been send to the controller.
It works perfectly when I choose dates manually or when the search button is clicked.
What shall I do??

Comment: did you check this two element in inside of form?

Comment: Before form submit does `value` where `name="from"` or `name="to"` exists? Perhaps it submits form before full loading all values in your view.

Comment: @AksenP what can be done to avoid it?? because these tags are inside form only

Comment: @badprogrammer, show me the way how you're submitting this form. If it's done via js/jquery -> one way is to add `setTimeout` function

Comment: It works perfectly when I choose dates manually . but only on page load it posts null date

Comment: @badprogrammer, show me submitting way

Comment: @AksenP I am using Codeigniter's form_open method to submit values

Comment: @badprogrammer, perfect, but you're pushing some button with `type="submit"` or using `$('form').submit()` in jquery, for example? Also, please, inspect this form, look at `value` before submit. It exists after page loading or not? I can help you, if I'll understand how does your mvc built

Comment: Try to replace `php argument of value` on this and tell me the result: `<?= empty($this->input->post('from')) ? date('Y-m-d') : $this->input->post('from'); ?>`, the same with `to`

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `php argument of value` on this:

```
<?= empty($this->input->post('from')) || !date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('from'))) ? date('Y-m-d') : $this->input->post('from'); ?>
```

the same with `to`. After this your form should looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-12 box-header">
    <?php echo form_open('admin/Inward/showreport', 'class="form-inline" style=""');?>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           <input 
                 id="date_1" 
                 value="<?= empty($this->input->post('from')) || !date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('from'))) ? date('Y-m-d') : $this->input->post('from'); ?>" 
                 name="from" 
                 class="form-control pull-left" 
                 type="date" 
                 placeholder=" From" />
            <p class="pull-left" style="font-size:10px;">From Date</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input 
                  id="date_2" 
                  value="<?= empty($this->input->post('to')) || !date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('to'))) ? date('Y-m-d') : $this->input->post('to'); ?>" 
                  name="to" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  type="date" 
                  placeholder=" To" />
            <p class="pull-left" style="font-size:10px;">To Date</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but still no result. I echoed my query which showed me value of to and from as 0.

Comment: @badprogrammer, updated, check it now. Both ways are working for me.